# Install Roundcube on vServer via Plesk 12 gives 403 forbidden

Tags: server, ubuntu-14.04, roundcube

I wanted to set up a mail server on my vServer hosted by Strato. The installation process seemed to easy, so I just installed the package via **Plesk 12** updater.. I expected it to be "ready-to-use" but all I have got is a 403 - Forbidden when I try to access the webmail on my vServer **(ubuntu 14.04 / webmail.mydomain.com)**

Most of the sources I have found doesn't cover my problem at all. And if there were similiar problems, they installed roundcube manually over the console. I could try to fix it over the console, too, but I don't want to mess up the automatically installed version of roundcube.

I mean, it seems to be there. I just don't have access to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1- Make sure your roundcube is found/moved in /var/www/ path.

2- Modify your apache config file in "let say" /etc/apache2/conf.d/Example.conf and use these configuration while editing paths for your roundcubemail depending on your current roundcube default configuration:

Alias /roundcube /var/www/roundcube/roundcubemail-0.3.1

< Directory /var/www/roundcube/roundcubemail-0.3.1 >

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

DirectoryIndex index.php

AllowOverride All

Order allow,deny

Allow from all

< IfModule mod_php4.c >

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

php_flag track_vars On

php_flag register_globals Off

php_value include_path .

< /IfModule >

< IfModule mod_php5.c >

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

php_flag track_vars On

php_flag register_globals Off

php_value include_path .

< /IfModule >

< /Directory>

3- If you encounter any php compatibility make sure to edit check.php in the installer folder and this will work for u.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your effort, but before I try your solution, let me ask: where do I find the roundcube directory? All I found was "/etc/psa-webmail/roundcube"

Comment: well you have to look for it in /usr/share/roundcube or /var/www/roundcube.. try looking there and if it's in /usr/share/roundcube then move it to /var/www/

Comment: It was in /usr/share/ but then the directory was quite different "psa-roundcube"...I moved it to /var/www/ but still get 403 forbidden

Comment: You moved it to /var/www and fixed the names as they should be? Did u fix Alias and Directory path in the web server configuration as well?

Comment: What do you mean by fix as they should be? I changed /var/www/roundcube/roundcubemail-0.3.1 to /var/www/roundcube in my apache2.conf. Do you mean this? If so, then yes